# PayPal Advanced Payments Simple Donation Form

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to put together a PayPal php form that will work with advanced payments where the user can enter the amount they want to donate. This needs to use PayPal Advanced Payments so it will all be processed on the website. I've searched all over but everything refers to using a shopping cart and purchasing items.

I don't need that. I just need the user to be able to enter the amount they want to donate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The guides that you're seeing that include a shopping cart would still follow the same procedure you need to do.  It's just that instead of calculating a total amount from a shopping cart you'll simply use the the amount entered by the user in a form.  Again, though, then you would just follow the same procedure the guides you've found use, except you'll pass that amount in instead of a shopping cart amount.

Answer (score 0):

The following link at page 5 was very helpful to me. I hope this helps.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf